# JPA ManyToMany relation infinite loop

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, lazy-initialization

I have two Entity objects ,whose fields are:

> Operation--> {id, name, applications}
>
> Application-->{id, name, operations}

As u can see, both of these objects can include each others list, so I do that like

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},targetEntity=Operation.class)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinTable(schema="RBMCORE",
          name="T_RBM_OPSCREENS_OPS_APPS",
          joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="APP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
          inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="OP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
```

other is

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy="operations",targetEntity=Application.class)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

Each of them has a definition like this(vice versa about join column part). But when I do this it gives an exception like

> "sessions are not exist or already closed"

.

When I make LazyInit as false, it enters to infinite loop , which is not a surprise.(Spring says the problem is because of JSON conversion of the object but I think it is still related with JPA)

What can I do about this problem? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have these annotations at both sides, then the mapping is wrong. One of the side must use the `mappedBy` attribute. See example 7.24 in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have made and it worked for the function method which fetches the operations. But now, JSON is entering in an infinite loop in order to create JSON form of the Object and I think the real reason about the JPA relations has not gone. I have edited the question

Comment: Are you sure its an infinite loop?  How many entities are in each collection?  A common mistake is mapping data that inadvertently brings in every object in the database.  Or enough to run out of stack space if using recursion to process objects.  If so, try only using a single relationship instead of bidirectional M:M.

Comment: Then tune the JSON marshalling. Obviously, you have to break the recursivity somewhere. This has nothing to do with JPA anymore.

Comment: At the phase of getting the object's JSON form, application digs the instance and in each digging  it will try to parse the object which has the reference of itself. So this can definitely be the case of the infinite loop because of recursiveness in my opinion.